# JSONAPI testing with rspec and Airborne

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

Hello i have problem with testing JSONAPI with rspec and airborne.
GET model below 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyf75.png

Im testing it this way https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9rHt.png

Rspec output:

Failures:
  1) GET on /contacts should validate types
     Failure/Error: expect_json('books.0', title: 'The Great Escape')

```
 Airborne::PathError:
   Expected NilClass
   to be an object with property 0
 # /home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/airborne-0.2.5/lib/airborne/path_matcher.rb:21:in `rescue in block in get_by_path'
 # /home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/airborne-0.2.5/lib/airborne/path_matcher.rb:18:in `block in get_by_path'
 # /home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/airborne-0.2.5/lib/airborne/path_matcher.rb:9:in `each'
 # /home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/airborne-0.2.5/lib/airborne/path_matcher.rb:9:in `each_with_index'
 # /home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/airborne-0.2.5/lib/airborne/path_matcher.rb:9:in `get_by_path'
 # /home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/airborne-0.2.5/lib/airborne/request_expectations.rb:137:in `call_with_path'
 # /home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/airborne-0.2.5/lib/airborne/request_expectations.rb:18:in `expect_json'
 # ./book_resource.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ------------------
 # --- Caused by: ---
 # NoMethodError:
 #   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
 #   /home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/airborne-0.2.5/lib/airborne/path_matcher.rb:57:in `process_json'
```

Finished in 0.03121 seconds (files took 0.17681 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Comment: Please post code instead of links to screenshots.

Comment: I cannot do this, cause too low rep

Answer (score 0):

Your API response doesn't have the key `books`. Instead, it is returning the response as `{ "data": [ ... ] }`.

So, in your tests, you need to specify `expect_json('data.0', ...)`, instead of `expect_json('books.0', ...)`.

Hope that should resolve this issue.

Comment: 1) GET on /users should return valid types
     Failure/Error: expect_json('data.1', name: "Jack McClure")

     Airborne::PathError:
       Expected NilClass
       to be an object with property 1
     1) GET on /users should return valid types
     Failure/Error: expect_json('data.1', name: "Jack McClure")
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # NoMethodError:
     #   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
     #   /home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/airborne-0.2.5/lib/airborne/path_matcher.rb:57:in `process_json'

Comment: Started GET "/api/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-23 12:18:20 +0100
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by Api::UsersController#index as XML
  Parameters: {"user"=>{}}
Filter chain halted as :ensure_valid_accept_media_type rendered or redirected
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 201ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)

Comment: @RobsonRbn I understand you have low rep, but you can use third-party tools like [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/) to show me your code. I cannot understand the logs in the comments.

Comment: so sorry i forgot about this

GET Request: http://pastebin.com/Bf4YB30n

Rspec run : http://pastebin.com/2F2mGFBd

Answer (score 0):

Already solve with:

describe Api::UsersController do
  describe 'GET on /users' do
    before do
      FactoryGirl.create('user', name: 'Jack McClure')
      FactoryGirl.create('user', name: 'Johny Reaper')
      FactoryGirl.create('user', name: 'Niko Bellic')
    end

```
it 'should return valid user' do
  get :index, format: 'json'
  expect_json('data.0.attributes', name: "Jack McClure")
  expect_json('data.2.attributes', name: 'Niko Bellic')
end
```

end